# Css Bootstrap spacing issue

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm using bootstrap and i've created a row with 3 columns. I have pictures in the columns and i want one of them to span the width of 2 columns. My initial thinking was to make the width: 200%; however, this doesn't take into account the gap between the css columns so it doesn't scale nicely.

My second problem is that the gaps between the vertical images aren't the same size as the column gaps.

[image]

HTML FILE:
        
        Sonder

```
    <meta name="Sonder" content="Great Donegal Food">
    <!--    CSS/BootStrap    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Fonts   -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abhaya+Libre" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Allows full width to be occupied -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- nav bar 12 column -->
    <ul class="topnav">
        <a href="#home"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Sonder"></a>
        <a href="http://localhost:8888"><li>Menu</li></a>
        <a href="#about"><li>About Us</li></a>
        <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
    </ul>
    </nav></div>
        <!-- col 1 start -->
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <img class="img_hover1" src="choc.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%;"></a>
        <img class="img_hover2" src="turkeyflat.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 2em;"></a>
        <img class="img_hover3" src="stirloin.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 2em;"></a>
        </div> <!-- col 1 end -->

        <!-- col 2 start -->
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>


        <img class="img_hover4" src="scones.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%;"></a>
        <img class="img_hover5" src="roast.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:205%; margin-top: 2em;"></a>
        </div> <!-- col 2 end-->

        <!-- col 3 start-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>


        <img class="img_hover6" src="hot_chocolate.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%;"></a>
        <img class="img_hover7" src="egg.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 2em;"></a>
        </div><!-- col 3 end-->
    </div> <!-- end of Row -->
    </div><!-- end of container-fluid -->


</body>
```

Comment: Your structure. Doesnt seem very correct. There are few unclosed tags (OR) they are placed are the wrong places, The `<nav>` has tow `<div>` starting in it but not ending within it

Comment: your structure has some issues(*unless that was you intension*) see my attempt at correcting it here - http://s.codepen.io/dex3844/debug/gLwNQo

Comment: Same problem though where the images dont scale :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
        <!-- col 1 start -->
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <br><br><br><br>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Chocolate Cake</h3>
                <p>Gourmet cake made from the finest italian chocolate and freshly prepared daily</p>
            </div> <!-- End of caption -->
            <img class="img_hover" src="choc.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; height: 350px;">

        <img class="img_hover" src="turkeyflat.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px;">
        <img class="img_hover" src="stirloin.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px;">
        </div> <!-- col 1 end -->

        <!-- col 2 start -->
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <br><br><br><br>
        <img class="img_hover" src="scones.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; height: 560px;">
        <!-- <img class="img_hover" src="roast.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:205%; margin-top: 2em;"> -->
        </div> <!-- col 2 end-->

        <!-- col 3 start-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <img class="img_hover" src="hot_chocolate.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; height: 265px;">
        <img class="img_hover" src="egg.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px; height: 265px;">
        </div><!-- col 3 end-->
```

The solution here cam in the form of nested columns:

```
        <!-- Leave column 1 empty -->
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <!-- Add the image into column 2 and make it 8 wide instead of 4 -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img class="img_hover" src="roast.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px; ">
        </div>
        <!-- Add any more pictures here by creating new columns at a width of your choosing -->

    </div> <!-- end of Row -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Runnable code with snippet**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <br><br><br><br>
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>Chocolate Cake</h3>
            <p>Gourmet cake made from the finest italian chocolate and freshly prepared daily</p>
        </div>

        <img class="img_hover" src="choc.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; height: 350px;">
        <img class="img_hover" src="turkeyflat.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px;">
        <img class="img_hover" src="stirloin.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px;">
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <br><br><br><br>
        <img class="img_hover" src="scones.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; height: 560px;">

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <img class="img_hover" src="hot_chocolate.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; height: 265px;">
        <img class="img_hover" src="egg.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px; height: 265px;">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4"></div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img class="img_hover" src="roast.jpg" alt="Sonder" style="width:100%; margin-top: 30px; ">
    </div>

</div>
```